# How to use keyboard controls with Need for Speed: The Run

Tags: keyboard, need-for-speed-the-run

When I play Need For Speed: The Run, all the onscreen prompts are to press "B" or "X" or "LT" (Left Trigger) for Xbox 360 controls.

How do I play this game with keyboard only?

Answer (score 2):

In the Main Menu, go to:

**Settings > Gameplay > Controls**

then change the **Input Device** to **Keyboard**.

If you still see the Xbox controller options in the menus and not the keyboard controls, you need to unplug any game controllers from your PC before booting the game (Joysticks, etc).